# Android Button reveal effect disappears when i set the background of button

Tags: android, button, android-theme

The on click button reveal effects disappear when i set background of a button in android,i am using this theme as my parent theme `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`
and i am setting the background for a button as this `android:background="#EE6C00"`